# allowTsInNodeModules similar option from ts-loader to parcel compiler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parceljs

I am looking to move away from webpack to parcel.

I have come into an issue of loading TypeScript directly from node modules and it causing a compiler error.

> Build failed.
>
> @parcel/transformer-js: Expected '>', got 'type'
> Blockquote

```
    94 |             <Button
  > 95 |                 type={'primary'}
  >    |                 ^^^^
    96 |                 onClick={this.onSubmitClick}
    97 |                 href={onSubmit.href}
```

Within our work, we have non transpiled TSX / TS being used across services, through webpack we used the ts-loader "allowTsInNodeModules" option to overcome this problem.

I have used the include node modules option from Parcel in hopes this would bundle it at run-time however it does not.

Is this a possibility in native Parcel? Or do I need to implement another loader within Parcel to get this functionality? Thanks!